# How can I create a Views type page without using Views?

Tags: 7, views, performance

I have a very intensive project that ultimately (and theoretically) was designed to house 33,600 Views pages. It's a census data project, and one page represents one city in the United States.

The URL structure MANDATORILY must follow this pattern:
example.com/Atlanta-GA or example.com/{cityname}-{state}

Originally, when trying to use Views as the direction, it was easy enough to create a page view with name "atlanta-ga." Then, as each page had attachments and other blocks specific to the data found for that particular location, it showed them on that page accordingly.  This approach worked well until we got to just over 1000 views.  (Of course, all these views are created programmatically from already existing data sets in other databases).

However, Views will not scale this high (because of memory leaks and existing limitations in Views current architecture predominantly.)

So then, how do I recreate this process programmatically without using Views? How can I create a page at the address example.com/{cityname}-{state} with related blocks, attachments, and tabs? How did people do this before Views was ever invented?

Here are a few links if you are interested in some other background questions related to this project and Drupal's ability to scale this high (or Views rather.)

http://groups.drupal.org/node/284998

Here Merlinofchaos, author of Views, states pretty much it's not possible to get views to scale this high. He notes that in many instances all of the views have to be loaded, which, will crash at these numbers.
http://drupal.org/node/1929938

All creative approaches to this problem appreciated.

Comment: Is it not possible to write a custom views handler, and use contextual filters? Possibly followed by using an url alias to get the correct URL structure?

Comment: hmm that's an interesting idea. Using one view with related filters has been suggested several times, but it never gave me my url structure.  So you are suggesting handling this at the url rewrite (mod_rewrite for me) level? How would that work? example.com/state/city => ex.com/state-city in .htaccess?

Comment: @blue928 you should be able to acheive it simply by manipulating the argument in "Specify validation criteria" (PHP Code) and "Provide default value" (PHP Code). I thought i would try it for you but didnt succeed at the moment :) (the idea is to give the view 2 contextual filters, link them to taxonomy or something and passing them the string from adress divided between the 2).

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?  I have a similar issue that I am trying to deal with...